# How can I modify the path to git repo in RStudio (.git in higher lever directory than .Rproj)?

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I have a git repo set up for MyProject. `.git` therefore resides in `~/MyProject/.git`. I split the main project into several sub projects, and now each of the sub projects has a respective `.Rproj` file generated by RStudio, like so:

```
~/MyProject/.git
~/MyProject/SubProject1/.Rproj
~/MyProject/SubProject2/.Rproj
etc..
```

The problem is that RStudio expects the respective `.git` folders to also reside in the SubProject folder and not one level higher, for example it wants:

```
~/MyProject/SubProject1/.git
```

Is there a way to point RStudio at the non-default location of the git repo in ~/MyProject/?